# Getting error: The service and account specified in key.json do not match the version of the toolbelt

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I am new at Salesforce DX. I am trying to connect to my account from sfdx plugin,

I typed in the terminal:

```
sfdx force:org:open -u my_username
```

but it gives me an error:

> ERROR running force:org:open:  The service and account specified in
>   key.json do not match the version of the toolbelt.

After extensive search, I couldn't find key.json file anywhere in my code.

The project contains only an empty project (sfdx:create project), and new empty lwc conponents.

Comment: What is the sourceApiVersion attribute value in the sfdx-project.json file? Is that version number the same as the org you're trying to authenticate into?

Comment: Yes, they both 45.0

Answer (score 6):

Running the plugin command `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/plugin-auth@1.4.3` in cmd resolved my above issue.

Comment: This worked. finally.. Thank you guys. @user92082

Comment: This worked for me too, thank you! Wish I had check the plugin version I had before to compare

Answer (score 2):

I needed to upgrade my auth plugin using the patch described [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/757).

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you have a ".sfdx" directory under your user profile directory:
      `C:/Users/<your username>` ( Windows)  or
      `/home/<your user name>` ( Unix ). 
 It has to have a `key.json` file with a key and service name as sfdx.

It won't be available by default after you install Sfdx CLI. Hence you need to login to SF first using the following command.

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login -d -a <any org name>
```

The above command will open up the default browser window, where you need to enter your Sales force credentials.

Once logged in with your credentials , it will ask whether you allow Salesforce CLI to perform a few things. say yes , and the login will be successful ( you will get a successful message in your command line window , where you invoked the command ) something like the below:

`Successfully authorized <your email id> with org ID <organization id>
You may now close the browser`

Now if you check the .sfdx folder/directory above you should have the key.json file. Further to this, you should not be getting this error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Running `sfdx update` through the command line resolved this issue for me. I got this key.json warning when trying to allow CLI access to my Salesforce org for the first time rather than when trying to open an already approved org though.